# Why does Django no longer consider mysqldb a valid backend?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-12.04

I am asking the following question here, because it involves developer tools.

I have upgraded my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS workstation to 12.04 LTS (32-bit). Today I went to try a Django web application that has been working without errors. It is running on Apache.

The application no longer works and returns an error. I  have been working through a series of errors all located in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

The first error involved UCS2 and UCS4 (lines trimmed for readability).

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: 
undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromObject
mod_wsgi (pid=9246): Target WSGI script 
'/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/wsgi_amr_handler.py' 
cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

That was cleared by rebuilding and re-installing the latest version of mod_wsgi.

The current error involves mysqldb not being a valid backend. Here is the error (timestamps removed for clarity):

```
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 51, 
in load_backend
raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql' isn't an available database backend.
Try using django.db.backends.mysql instead.
Error was: No module named mysql.base
```

Is this a configuration problem in the Django application's settings.py or something else?

Is there an installation order for Python 2.7, mod_wsgi, Django, and mysqldb, and could that be the problem?

Here is my current (after receiving comments) settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': ' django.db.backends.mysql', 
'NAME': 'server',      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
'USER': 'ox',          # Not used with sqlite3.
'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
'HOST': '',     
'PORT': '',  
    }
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: ' django.db.backends.mysql' isn't an available database backend.
Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named  django.db.backends.mysql.base
```

Comment: There is no preferred installation order for those packages. It is quite possible that your django version was upgraded and you had an older `settings.py` format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You apparently upgraded you Django installation as well. Recent Django versions need the *full* name of the backend module. The way you specify databases was changed in [version 1.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.2/#features-deprecated-in-1-2) and you'll need to follow the upgrade notes to update your Django project codebase.

For MySQL the correct backend is now [`django.db.backends.mysql`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database); open `settings.py` and update your `DATABASES` entry.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: You have an extra space in your `ENGINE` entry, at the start. Remove it; `' django.db.backends.mysql'` is not a valid module name with the starting space there and that's what is confusing Django now.